# My XtraReport does not contain new data added

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

I have a crud application (winForms App using c# ),
I want to display the data into an XtraReport , the problem is that the data is displayed only when I re-run the application.
I will explain more :

1) I run the app

2) I add data in my database

3) I click on the button to display the report , but it contain only the old data

4) I close the app and run it again , click the button to display the report ,Now  the new data is displayed

for the The report dataSource i use an existing connectionString.
 any solution !!

Comment: have you tried to update data at BeforePrint event?? try this hope you will get solution..

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your code? Are you using `binding source` or `procedure` to `select data`? May be you have to refill your `binding source`. Check your `report datasource` that contains data you want in `BeforePrint event`.